# R: how to combine ggplots basd on data with different column names

Tags: r, ggplot2

Both ggplots below work separtely, but I would like to combine them to one plot where the `Group` variable of the lines in `df2` appears in the legend.

```
library(ggplot2)
df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)
df2 <- data.frame(x = rep(1:10,2), 
        y = c(seq(1,2,length.out = 10),
        seq(5,6,length.out = 10)), 
        Group = c(rep("A",10),rep("B",10))          
        )

p1 <- ggplot(data = df1, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
geom_point() 

p2<- ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = x, y = y,
group = Group, color = Group)) + 
geom_line()
```

[image: 2 ggplots that I want to combine into 1]

The problem is caused by the fact that 2 data frames have different column names. Therefore I cannot generate 2 plots and add them like `p1 + p2` as it is done in other solutions that have been published here before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in `ggplot2` each layer has its own local `data` argument, i.e. you could pass a different dataset to each layer. If you don't set the `data` argument for a layer it will simply inherit the global dataset set in `ggplot()` (if any), i.e. you could combine your plots into one by adding `+ geom_line(data = df2, aes(group = Group, color = Group))` to your first plot.

Second, if your datasets have different column names that's not a big deal either. As with the `data` argument, each layer has it's own (local) set of aesthetics. If not set, a layer will inherit the global aesthetics set in `ggplot()`, i.e. with different column names you simply have to tell which columns should be mapped on the aesthetics in each layer.

Slightly altered your example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)
df1 <- data.frame(x1 = 1:10, y1 = 1:10)
df2 <- data.frame(x2 = rep(1:10,2), 
                  y2 = c(seq(1,2,length.out = 10),
                        seq(5,6,length.out = 10)), 
                  Group = c(rep("A",10),rep("B",10))          
)

ggplot(data = df1, aes(x = x1, y = y1)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data = df2, aes(x = x2, y = y2, group = Group, color = Group))
```

[image]